# How do I find out if a patent is still active?

Tags: abandoned-patent

I was granted a patent in 1994 and was unable to pay maintenance fees; therefore I lost the patent. I am looking to see if someone has gained control of it.

Comment: If you provide a patent number, we can potentially provide more specific information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible for someone other than the assignee to "gain control" of an abandoned patent. Regardless, A patent issued in 1994 will almost certainly have expired by the time of your question regardless of maintenance fees. US patents back then expired either 17 years from the grant date or 20 years from the priority date whichever was later. International patents were generally 20 years from the priority or filing date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the USPTO's public PAIR database to see what has become of the patent including any assignments:  http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair

Comment: This would be a better answer if it wasn't only US patent specific.